# Get smaller value in 3rd column R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Data frame

```
year1 year2
2009   2002
2003   2010
2005   2005
2006   2005
2005   NA
NA     2006
```

I want a 3rd column to have the smaller value by comparing both the columns.
so the output be like

```
year1 year2  year
2009   2002  2002
2003   2010  2003
2005   2005  2005
2006   2005  2005 
2005   NA    2005
NA     2006  2006
```

For my approach I changed NA's to 1 adn then comparing both the columns, but it will only give me the higher value or wrong value as on the other side if i use:
less than then it will only give me 1 in the column that is not correct.

```
 startdate$year<-ifelse(as.numeric(startdate$year1)==as.numeric(startdate$year2),
                       startdate$year1,startdate$year)

startdate$year<-ifelse(as.numeric(startdate$year1)<as.numeric(startdate$year2),
                       startdate$year2,startdate$year)

startdate$year<-ifelse(as.numeric(startdate$year1)>as.numeric(startdate$year2),
                       startdate$year1,startdate$year)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that with `pmin`

```
df$year = pmin(df$year1, df$year2, na.rm=TRUE)
df
  year1 year2 year
1  2009  2002 2002
2  2003  2010 2003
3  2005  2005 2005
4  2006  2005 2005
5  2005    NA 2005
6    NA  2006 2006
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `apply` with `min`.

```
dat$year <- apply(dat, 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
dat
#   year1 year2 year
# 1  2009  2002 2002
# 2  2003  2010 2003
# 3  2005  2005 2005
# 4  2006  2005 2005
# 5  2005    NA 2005
# 6    NA  2006 2006
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "year1 year2
2009   2002
                  2003   2010
                  2005   2005
                  2006   2005
                  2005   NA
                  NA     2006",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: hey can you explain what does "1" mean in
 apply(dat, 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: @Rishi Sure. 1 means do the operation by row. 2 means by column.

Comment: Oh okay now i got it

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version with `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
   mutate(year = pmap(., min, na.rm = TRUE))
#  year1 year2 year
#1  2009  2002 2002
#2  2003  2010 2003
#3  2005  2005 2005
#4  2006  2005 2005
#5  2005    NA 2005
#6    NA  2006 2006
```

Or with `pmin` and if there are many columns,

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(year = pmin(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)), na.rm = TRUE))
```